# Server unavailable alert pop up in MAC OS Lion

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion

In my application, I am presenting a screen which displays the computer name. But when I tested the application, in one of the machine I am getting an error saying

> There was a problem connecting to the server “xxx.xxx.xx.xxx”.The server may not exist or it is unavailable at this time. Check the server name or IP address, check your network connection, and then try again.

When I click ok of this alert my application resumes it's operation. But it was basically hanged till I got this alert. Any idea what the issue is? Please note I am not getting this alert in all machines.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code are you using to display the name?

Comment: I am using CSCopyMachineName() method to get the machine name.